# ng-click api search with AngularjS

Tags: angularjs

I wonder how to connect the search button to the input field.

**controllers.js**

```
  angular.module('weatherApp.controllers', [])
 .controller('weatherCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

     $http.jsonp('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=' + $scope.SearchCity + '&type=like&APPID=&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')             
         .success(function(data){
             console.log('success');
             $scope.cities = data;

     });

});
```

**all.html**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="SearchCity" placeholder="Search for city" />
<input type="submit" ng-click="Search" Value="Search" />

<tr ng-repeat="city in cities.list | limitTo: 10 | filter:SearchCity">
  <td>{{city.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('weatherApp', ['weatherApp.controllers', 'ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/all', {templateUrl: 'templates/all.html', controller:'weatherCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/all'});
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

Controller:

```
.controller('weatherCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.cities = [];

  $scope.callOpenWeatherMap = function(searchCity){
    $http.jsonp('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=' + searchCity + '&type=like&APPID=&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
      .then(function(data){
        console.log('success', data);
        $scope.cities = data;
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log('error', error);

    });
  };

});
```

HTML:

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchCity" placeholder="Search for city" />
  <input type="submit" ng-click="callOpenWeatherMap(searchCity)" Value="Search" />

  <tr ng-repeat="city in cities.list | limitTo: 10 | filter:searchCity">
    <td>{{city.name}}</td>
  </tr>
```

UPDATE

To improve your code you could create an OpenWeatherMap service where place all mathods/calls to the OpenWeatherMap api:

Service:

```
.service('OpenWetherMap', function($http){

  this.find = function(searchCity){
    return $http.jsonp('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=' + searchCity + '&type=like&APPID=&callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
  };

})
```

Controller:

```
.controller('weatherCtrl', function($scope, OpenWetherMap) {

  $scope.callOpenWeatherMap = function(searchCity){
    OpenWetherMap.find(searchCity).then(function(data){
      console.log('success', data);
      $scope.cities = data;
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log('error', error);
    });
  };

});
```

Comment: I get this in mozilla console: success Object { data: Object, status: 200, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "load" }. it doesnt list the cities im searching for though

Comment: Try changing this line to: console.log('success', data.data);

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding what you're asking, but you should be able to wrap your jsonp call in a `$scope.Search` function?

Comment: I fairly new to coding and not sure what you  mean with wrapping. For example, when I write stockholm in the search field I want to it to put the input data into the $scope.searchCity. But I still don't know how ng-click is working

Comment: `$scope.Search = function () {  $http.jsonp(...); }`

Comment: I've been struggleing with it since I don't know how to connect the button to my input field. That's what im looking for! :)

Comment: You are including SearchCity in your jsonp call. That is set with ng-model. Your ng-click should call Search as a function e.g. `ng-click="Search()"`